# How to overcome this situation Windows Services App

Tags: c#, methods, windows-services

I've created folder by userName in protected OnStart but I want to create out of Onstart method my codes is working but I dont know to create out of OnStart method.Can you help me? thank you.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    this.myTimer.Enabled = true;
    string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\ST\" + userName);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by out of OnStartMethod ?

Comment: Need proper explanation..

Comment: I mean that I want to call below codes by method or functions in OnStart.I should write below codes in anymethod and I should call this method in protected OnStar method. 

     string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\ST\" + userName);

Comment: I'm late I am new and click answer question showed warning: you have reputation and predict that I have activated member and ı looked for other question for asking because of higher reputation.End I find ADD comment section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Syaman: I have just tested the code below and it works. I hope this is what you were looking for.  If it is please make this question as answered.

```
  protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
  {
      CreatFolder();
  }

  public static void CreatFolder()
  {
      //this.myTimer.Enabled = true;
      string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
      Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\ST\" + userName);
  }
```

Comment: @Syaman: the above code works regardless if it is a console application or a service.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to understand your question but I think you are looking at something like the following; if not can you please extend your question.

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

       testc(); 
    }


    public static void testc()
    {

    }
```

After your last comment I have added the following code. The OnStart method will launch a thread and start the desired method:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    m_Run = true;

    Thread LoadNewData = new Thread(ImportNewData);
    LoadNewData.Start();

}

public void ImportNewData()
{
     while(true)
        {
            //do stuff here
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes I mean like that but I am curious about how to call this method (it means testc) in OnStart.

Comment: @Syaman: I see I forgot to call the testc method in my OnStart method. I have changed my code above.

Comment: it seems working by built however when I insert on my computer by windows services application it is not working.Why?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? If possible post the code you have now so that you can try help

Comment: Sure it seems correct but it isnot working here you are:         protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            this.myTimer.Enabled = true;
            testc();
          
           
        }
        public static void testc()
        {
            string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\ST\" + userName);
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
         
            this.myTimer.Enabled = false;
        }

Comment: I dont take an error but this code hasnt created userName Folder

Comment: :sorry as I said ,I am new and I am waiting other answer I dont see editing.I will try again.thank you for tolerance and support

Comment: Now returns Error1The name 'm_Run' does not exist in the current context

Comment: m_Run is a global variable of boolean type. It was just code I cut and paste. However above is a working example.

Comment: unfortunately it maybe work on console but its not windows service application.